# How To Autowire a String MVC Session Scoped Bean Into RestEasy Client Interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, resteasy

I am consuming a rest api created using RestEasy in a Spring  MVC based front end.

There are two WAR projects being developed.

1. RestEasy + Spring IOC based REST API
2. Spring MVC + Spring IOC + RestEasy Client Proxy based front end.

I am using RestEasy Client Proxy for calling the rest services. The JAX-RS contract interfaces are shared on both side the RestEasy API side as well as in Spring MVC application.

In a Spring MVC + Spring IOC + RestEasy Client Proxy based project,
I am trying to autowire a session scoped bean into a RestEasy ClinetInterceptor which is define in a Spring MVC controller.

I have used annotations. But still I get NPE on the Autowired Session Scoped bean inside ClientInterceptor..

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

To inject session scoped beans in singleton bean / prototype scoped beans , session scoped beans should be declared with scoped proxy as Spring inject bean proxy as placeholder of the bean.

Session scoped bean can be declared as scoped proxy by,

In XML declaration,

```
 <bean ... scope="session"> 
   <aop:scoped-proxy/> 
 </bean>
```

if you are using Annotations,

```
@Scope(value="session",proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

proxy mode provide information about what type of proxy to generate, interface based/ class based.